# Command prompt ssms.exe login with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, azure, cmd, ssms, azure-sql-database

Following this [msdn guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825.aspx) I'm trying to connect to azure server through command prompt by typing this command:

```
ssms.exe -S myserver.database.windows.net -D mydatabase -E
```

SQL Server Managment Studio starts but I then see this error:

"Cannot connect to myserver.database.windows.net. Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

This is very strange because I can connect passing the values `-U` and `-P` and I also can connect to Azure Portal through browser and relative Windows Authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting with -U and -P works because it's SQL auth. The browser already supports integrated auth so if you have your local AD federated with AAD, you can login to your Azure subscription without needing to provide a UserID and password manually. The browser takes care of the token passing work silently.

There's a bit more work to do to use SSMS with Windows Integrated auth on Azure SQL DB. It was released in preview mode late last year. See announcement https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/09/16/azure-active-directory-authentication-is-in-public-preview/ and detailed instructions on how to enable here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/